# how to refresh listview with sqlite DB

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, refresh, row

im trying to refresh my listview after i deleted a row from SQLite DB.
This is part of it:

```
cursor = mysqlAdapter.fetchAll(); // a method from sqlite adater class 
ArrayList<MyInfo> vidRows = new ArrayList<MyInfo>(); 
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
do { ...... } 
while (cursor.moveToNext()); } 
mList.setAdapter(new SomeAdapter(this, vidRows)); 
mList.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
registerForContextMenu(mList); }
```

Then in my getView i do:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
View vidRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.queue_row, null); 
ImageView vidThumb = (ImageView) vidRow .findViewById(R.id.Thumb); 
Bitmap bmThumbnail; bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                     getFullpath(vidItems.get(position).my_id), Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);      
vidThumb.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail); 
TextView vidText = (TextView) vidRow .findViewById(R.id.vid_cap);
videoText.setText(vidItems.get(position).my_cap); return vidRow; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a cursor? If so you can just call:

```
cursor.requery();
```

Comment: That comes with a few [caveats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery()), but it works.

Comment: fair nuff. I have used it in the past for a delete only, but for sorting or anything else I request a new cursor.

Comment: i am using cursor to query the DB. I have tried cursor.requery() but it doesnt work.

Comment: I know you're using a cursor to query the DB but I don't know how you're populating your listview, SimpleCursorAdapter? If so then after you delete your row, you call requery it should work.

Comment: In the listview screen i just show each row with the new data from the DB...sample in oncreate:  cursor = mysqlAdapter.fetchAll(); // a method from sqlite adater class

  ArrayList<MyInfo> vidRows = new ArrayList<MyInfo>();
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   do { ......
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
               }
  mList.setAdapter(new SomeAdapter(this, vidRows));
  mList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  registerForContextMenu(mList);
              }

Comment: Then in my getView i do: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View vidRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.queue_row, null);

   ImageView vidThumb = (ImageView) vidRow
     .findViewById(R.id.Thumb);

   Bitmap bmThumbnail;
   bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
     getFullpath(vidItems.get(position).my_id),
     Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
   vidThumb.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

   TextView vidText = (TextView) vidRow
     .findViewById(R.id.vid_cap);
   videoText.setText(vidItems.get(position).my_cap);

   return vidRow;
  }

Comment: Can you update your question with this code (formatted) and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a list to populate your ListView? I would prefer doing it manually like this -

```
myList.remove(delPos);
getListView().invalidateViews();
```

Comment: no i am not using a list...im using cursor with DB and some images from a folder.                                             Anyone.....?

Comment: I saw your code above in the comments. You are using vidRows to populate your list. This code should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old but I'll reply in case anyone else have the same issue and it can help.

You could use a cursor adapter and pass the cursor to it using swapCursor (also works when using onCursorLoader) then whenever you delete a row you could do one of the follow:

1. delete a row from your db outside of the adapter and then call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

or

1. embed the db inside your adapter and create a delete method so when you call adapter.delete() is updates both the list (if you still use it) and the db.